# Firefox extension. How to access "browser" namespace from console?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying of the console to access the "browser" environment e.x. `browser.cookies.getAll` but this not defined anywhere except extension environment.

If make simple firefox addon (extension) with one .js file where browser API request:
`browser.cookies.getAll({}).then(console.log);`

get an array with an interactive preview.

Execute from extension

[image: Execute from extension]

If execute this command in console

[image: Execute from console]

How to access "browser" namespace from console?

Comment: Are you trying this to to test your extension and debug it? If so I might have a solution. Extension context is protected for security reasons. There is no way of accessing it from the command in console.

Comment: Yes, I tested the extension and debugged it. What solution do you have? Create an extension for executing commands?))

Comment: My solution involves a little bit of knowledge about testing in Javascript. Do you know any testing frameworks? Example jest, chai, mocha... If so, you can mock the browser.anyCommand and execute that as a nodejs script. This will help you make sure your extension works as you expected without testing it on browser console. Tell me if you want a detailed example and I'll post an answer. This is how I test my extensions and I don't have to reload the extension in the browser every time I change my code.

Comment: Please know that, you can't execute browser command from console, it is a security guard. Browser command have a lot more power than normal Javascript code when executed from console. The only way is to write a script and then inject it into your page and then execute the script. But this isn't a good idea. A good solution is a TDD (test driven development) approach.

Comment: Yes, I know testing frameworks but did not work with them. Give your detailed example. I will try to apply in practice or return to your solution when there will be more experience. **Don't have to reload the extension in the browser every time change code** - I like it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible, `browser.*` or `chrome.*` are not available on developer console because they need an extension's context to run and developer console runs commands on the context of current page.

The following approach requires learning/knowledge of unit testing and integration testing in JavaScript and node.js, the example provided is over-simplified, this is by no means production ready code.

---

A better approach for testing your extensions and debugging it is to write tests for it.

1. Choose a testing framework (Jest, Mocha + chai, etc) and set it up according to your needs
2. Install [sinon-chrome](https://github.com/acvetkov/sinon-chrome/) package which provides you with **stubs** for `browser.*` methods/apis by running `npm install --save-dev sinon-chrome`
3. (Optional) Install [webextensions-api-fake](https://github.com/webexts/webextensions-api-fake) which provides you with **mocks** for `browser.*` methods/apis by running `npm install --save-dev webextensions-api-fake`
4. (Optional) Install [webextensions-jsdom](https://github.com/webexts/webextensions-jsdom) which helps you to write tests for your browser_action default_popup, sidebar_action default_panel or background page/scripts
5. Start writing tests by following the example below
6. In order to debug your extension, set a breakpoint in your IDE/Editor of choice and run the tests, the execution will stop at the breakpoint and you will have access the states of Objects and Variables at that time in execution. This will help you know what and how exactly things are executing and what's happening to the data you pass around in functions. There is no need for writing `console.log` statements everywhere for checking your output or variables, debuggers can help with that.
7. (Optional) [webextensions-toolbox](https://github.com/webextension-toolbox/webextension-toolbox) is another great tool for writing cross-browser extensions (Your extension will work on chrome, firefox, opera, edge) with the same code base. This also comes with hot-reloading of your extension `page`, so you don't have to hit refresh every time you make any changes.

By following this approach, it will improve your development workflow and will reduce the number of times you have to hit refresh on your browser.

Example usage of sinon-chrome stubs using jest testing framework.
Lets say you have written your code in `yourModule.js` then to test/verify that it works in
`yourModule.test.js` you write:

```
import browser from 'sinon-chrome';
import yourModule from './lib/yourModule';

describe('moduleName', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    // To make sure yourModule uses the stubbed version
    global.browser = browser;
  });
  it('does something', async () => {
    await yourModule();
    // Lets assume your module creates two tabs
    expect(browser.tabs.create.calledTwice).toBe(true);
    // If you want to test how those browser methods where called
    expect(browser.tabs.create.firstCall.calledWithExactly({
      url: 'https://google.com',
    })).toBe(true);
    // Notice the usage of `.firstCall` here, this makes sure only the first time 
    // `browser.tabs.create` was called with the given args.
  });
});
```

When you run this test using jest, yourModule will expect there to exist a global variable `browser` with the apis it uses which is only possible in a real browser, but we faked it using the sinon-chrome package, your module will execute in node.js environment as expected.

You don't need to run it in the browser to see changes. You just write tests, write code to pass those tests and when all tests pass. Check your extension by running it in the browser, at this point in time your extension will run as you'd expect it to. If you add another feature to yourModule and your tests fail you know exactly what went wrong.

However the above example only makes sure how `browser.*` methods/apis were called, for you to test the behavior of yourModule you'd need to mock those methods/apis, this is were the webextensions-api-fake package comes in. You can find [example](https://github.com/webexts/webextensions-api-fake) in its repo on github.

Examples for testing your browser_action default_popup, sidebar_action default_panel or background page/scripts are also provided in the [webextensions-jsdom](https://github.com/webexts/webextensions-jsdom) repo on github.

Comment: This answer contains a bunch of unneeded info. The question is about how to access "browser" namespace, not about JavaScript mocking frameworks. There're other uses to access that namespace, like, heck, controlling your own browser. Note there's also "Browser Toolbox" thingy: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Toolbox , but "browser" isn't accessible from there either.

Comment: OP wanted to access `browser.*` apis from a tab's context in developer console. OP's reason was to test their extension. Those apis are only available in a real browser's extension context, So I provided an alternative.

if your intentions are to those apis for the sake of playing with them you can do that by
1. Go to about:addons
2. From the gear icon-> Debug addons or directly visit about:debugging#/runtime/this-firefox
3. Select any extension you have installed Or create dummy
4. Click inspect. And you will have the familiar developer console with `browser.*` apis available

Comment: thank you for such a thorough answer @user6552940!